# Check user have account in Instagram without redirecting abd login into instagram

Tags: php, redirect, authentication, instagram

I am new here so please ignore by grammatical mistakes. i am working on the php site where we need to check whether user having account in Instagram or not by username and password, without redirecting to Instagram site nor login into Instagram site.

Same as https://instagress.com/

After we signup, it asks instagram username and password, if we enter wrong username or password then it show error message. If details are correct then it show next page but we are not login in Instagram too. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

You can check if user having account in Instagram just only by his `LOGIN` or `USER-ID`.

For `LOGIN`:

You may check if page `https://instagram.com/LOGIN/` exists and consist user's data.

You may search user by login with API: `https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q=LOGIN&client_id=CLIENT-ID` and search `LOGIN` in response (`count=1` not work as expected). [Read more about Search Endpoint](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users_search).

For `USER-ID`:

You may check it only with API: `https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/USER-ID/?client_id=CLIENT-ID`. For private accounts it also return mistake, but the mistake is different for private accounts and deleted accounts.

About API (`USER-ID` and `CLIENT-ID`) [read more here](http://instagram.com/developer/).